# container-fluid padding issue in my Bootstrap templete

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap template where I have used bootstrap 3.3.6. In [here](https://www.bootply.com/4JVIj49PO0) its working fine. But In my project I have used same CSS and same markup code but I get white-space padding. How can I solve this problem?

In my project **[Issue](http://prntscr.com/fz5qzv)**

```css
.backXti {
  background: url(http://ginpass.com.mx/images/fondo_xit.jpg) no-repeat center center /cover;
}

#headerInterna {
  padding: 80px 0px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.blanco {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row backXti">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center" id="headerInterna">
      <h1 class="blanco ginFontN"><strong>Paquetes GINpass</strong></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <a href="/que_es_ginpass#DescuentoNomina">
      <img src="http://ginpass.com.mx/images/banner.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't see any padding in snippet.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov check this please http://prntscr.com/fz5qzv

Comment: OK, but I can't reproduce this using code.

Comment: this padding set in your container-fluid class.you can add Other class for container-fluid (`<div class="container-fluid a">`) and add css for `.a{
  padding-left:0px !importent;
} `.you can try After Comment please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this template its have:

```
.row {
     width: 100%;
} 
.row {
     margin-left: -15px;
     margin-right: -15px;
}
```

If i remove the `width` of `row` then its perfectly work.

Answer (score 0):

You can set

```
width: 100%;
```

to this img

```
<img src="http://ginpass.com.mx/images/banner.jpg" class="img-responsive">
```

like

```
.container-fluid .row img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```css
.backXti {
  background: url(http://ginpass.com.mx/images/fondo_xit.jpg) no-repeat center center /cover;
}

#headerInterna {
  padding: 80px 0px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.blanco {
  color: #fff;
}

.container-fluid .row img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row backXti">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center" id="headerInterna">
      <h1 class="blanco ginFontN"><strong>Paquetes GINpass</strong></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <a href="/que_es_ginpass#DescuentoNomina">
      <img src="http://ginpass.com.mx/images/banner.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It not width problem i think. I have tried in your way but not working. Take a look my issue http://prntscr.com/fz5qzv

Comment: Oh, OK.
Seems like this is not an error for this piece of code...
But, you can try set `container-fluid{width: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0}`